# ImageView image size

Tags: android, imageview

As far as I know, if image is too big, it can't be displayed in some fixed size `ImageView`. My question is how can I find out maximum size of image that can be displayed if I know width and height of `ImageView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android can display bitmaps up to 2048x2048 pixels. It dependents on OpenGL implementation.
But the main issue with big images is a insufficient memory problem. Big images takes more memory and leads to `OutOfMemoryError` and app crash.
The best way is scale image before displaying to `ImageView` size. There is a lot of image loading frameworks that can help you. For example [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco), [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)